# How to retrieve container ID BEFORE docker-compose build?

Tags: python, docker, celery

I want to deploy my webapp with docker. The webapp deals with a couple of long running tasks, so celery is in use. 
Since i need to retrieve information regarding the task, i hardcoded the part of celery inspect. See subsequent code snippet:

```py
i = celery.control.inspect()
    activetasks = i.active()
    list_of_tasks = {'activetasks': activetasks}
    task_id = list_of_tasks['activetasks']['celery@web'][0]['id']
```

**Main problem:**
At the time i do `sudo docker-compose build` i don't know the container's ID, which is an integral part since i need it to access the respective part in the returned dictionary. But i need to know the ID before i build the containers, due to the aforementioned code snippet.

I already assigned hostnames to all services within docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  web:
     build: ./web
     container_name: web
     hostname: web
...
```

I hoped that assigning a hostname would enable me to refer to it within the code (this is why the code states `celery@web`). But that is not the case, as you see in the below trace log:

`celery_1    | File "/app/tasks.py", line 121, in WorkflowStarten
celery_1    | task_id = list_of_tasks['activetasks']['celery@web'[0]['id']
celery_1    | KeyError: 'celery@web' 
web         | {'celery@6557dbca88b7': [{'id': '6a927dad-b09a-4728-a7a4-313ba4e582ff', 'name': 'WorkflowStarten', 'args': ['bla', 'bla123'], 'kwargs': {}, 'type': 'WorkflowStarten', 'hostname': 'celery@6557dbca88b7', 'time_start': 1564913745.6002579, 'acknowledged': True, 'delivery_info': {'exchange': '', 'routing_key': 'celery', 'priority': 0, 'redelivered': False}, 'worker_pid': 9}]}`

So i'm looking for a possibility to refer to the (web) container's id, since this is part of the returned dictionary of celery `task_id = list_of_tasks['activetasks']['celery@web'[0]['id']` BEFORE the container is built with `docker-compose build`.

Is this even possible? I'm afraid that it might not be. But if so, how to refer to the host's name within the code?

Comment: I think you'd be much better off trying to debug the hostname connectivity issues than this `docker inspect` path – the container ID will change any time you `docker run` a new container or otherwise restart this stack, and if you're starting things with `docker-compose up --build` it's possible all of the images will be built before any containers get started.

Comment: You also might consider just iterating through `activetasks.keys()` to get the worker IDs if you don't have a specific reason to be looking for a specific one.

Comment: Thank you, David, once again! Indeed i implemented the little workaround with a iteration ```for key in activetasks.keys(): ...``` . Its already working. Thanks, enjoy your sunday!